# Using axios to execute a post request in nodejs but I am not able to receive data in the post route

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am trying to execute a post request using axios but the req.body is showing empty object .  Here is my code :

```
 const postData = {
    tournamentId: tournamentId,
    category: category,
    contestantId: contestantId,
  };

  axios.post(`${process.env.URL}/joinTournament`, postData)
          .then((res) => {
              console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`);
              console.log("Body: ", res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
```

Comment: Are you using ```express.js``` in nodejs side? if yes, did you inject ```body-parser``` as middleware to your express app or router?

Comment: Echoing the comment above, please post your server-side code - how is the POST route handled?

Comment: If you are using `body-parser` middleware make sure that `Content-Type` is declared in the request header. If not include it; in you case: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thank you guys but I have found a solution . Sorry for the late comment , I was not well .

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things like test your backend logic with Postman (An API Development Tool). Then try to console log your request in backend to confirm the request reaching is correct.

If all that checkout turn to your libraries if you are using expressjs try to use a middleware like body-parser and cors to send back responses

The Code being something like

For Cors

```
//Cors
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(69, function () {
   console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

For Body-parser

```
//body-parser
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }))

// parse an HTML body into a string
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' })
```

Might as well setup a checker block where you'd check that if the request is missing some necessary info to send back some understandable response.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using qs and calling stringify method on postData . Here is my solution :

```
const qs = require("qs");
 const postData = {
    tournamentId: tournamentId,
    category: category,
    contestantId: contestantId,
  };

  axios.post(`${process.env.URL}/joinTournament`, qs.stringify(postData))
          .then((res) => {
              console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`);
              console.log("Body: ", res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if your server works very well with request from `postman` and every things is Ok, you can do like this, without third party module
[image]